# Why does a pointer to a base class with a different address compare equal to the derived class pointer

Tags: c++, object, pointers, language-lawyer

The standard defines pointer comparison like this basically from [expr.eq#3]

> Otherwise, if the pointers are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address, they compare equally.

Representing the same address means this from [basic.compound#def:represents_the_address]

> A value of a pointer type that is a pointer to or past the end of an object represents the address of the first byte in memory ([intro.memory]) occupied by the object34 or the first byte in memory after the end of the storage occupied by the object, respectively

So it is really about the address, but if so then why this code does not fail as technically **d_ptr** and **b_ptr** point to objects with different addresses? This looks like it is about **objects**, rather than **addresses** as complier can figure out both d_ptr and b_ptr point to the same complete object at the end!

```
struct B { int a;};
struct B1 { int b; };
struct D : B, B1 {};
struct A {};
....
D obj;
D *d_ptr = &obj;
B1 *b_ptr = d_ptr;
assert(d_ptr == b_ptr);//should have failed as d_ptr and b_ptr point to objects with diffrent addresses!
```

Comment: the code doesn't fail because the compiler does this `(static_cast<B1 *>(d_ptr) == b_ptr)`, as it can't compare pointers of different types, to force it to fail you can cast both to `void*`, this has nothing to do with the standard.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Yeah I see, fair enough

Comment: Even if there wasn't an implicit conversion changing the address, then the assert may still succeed. `B1` is permitted to have offset zero in `D`, although I am not aware of an ABI doing it that way.

Comment: It is a bold position to claim the standard as "wrong".  You will almost always be incorrect.    You might want to avoid such strident assertions (pun intended).

Comment: @Clifford   I agree.   The standard is THE definitive basis on which correctness (through compliance) or otherwise of implementations is assessed so, by definition, it cannot be wrong.    It is often fair to claim the standard has defects (which, say, affect utility of the language or standard library) since the standard evolves through versions to address those.     Too often, people treat an implementation (particular compiler and library) as the yardstick of correctness, which simply shows lack of understanding of the purpose of a standard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing [this passage](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#3)

> If at least one of the operands is a pointer, pointer conversions, function pointer conversions, and qualification conversions are performed on both operands to bring them to their composite pointer type.

A pointer conversion can change the address that the pointer represents, and that's exactly what happens in your case.

Comment: Too concise and to the point to have been written by any (current generation) AI ;-)

Answer (score 6):

In the expression `d_ptr == b_ptr` there is an implicit conversion of `d_ptr` to `B1*` - the common base class.  When this happens the addresses are equal, so the standard is not "*wrong*" - the conversion is also defined in the standard.

So for example, with an explicit conversion (in the second line):

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(b_ptr) << " != " << static_cast<void*>(d_ptr) << '\n' ;
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(b_ptr) << " == " << static_cast<void*>(static_cast<B1*>(d_ptr)) << '\n' ;
```

Output (in my test):

```
0x7ffdefb36204 != 0x7ffdefb36200
0x7ffdefb36204 == 0x7ffdefb36204
```

The second showing that an *explicit* conversion modifies the address.  An implicit conversion is no different.

Conversely:

```cpp
void* b_addr = b_ptr ;
void* d_addr = d_ptr ;
assert( d_addr == b_addr ) ;
```

results in:

```
a.out: main.cpp:24: int main(): Assertion `d_addr == b_addr' failed.
```

That is a direct address comparison without conversion to the common base fails as you would expect.  Similarly, without the intermediate pointers:

```cpp
assert( static_cast<void*>(d_ptr) == static_cast<void*>(b_ptr) ) ;
```

will also fail.